# Como enviar notificações de um site para o usuário pelo Browser

Tags: wordpress, navegador-de-internet, push-notification

Olá, tenho um site em **wordpress** e gostaria de enviar notificações para o usuário pelo browser como na imagem abaixo:

[image: O Problema]

Existe alguma forma de implementar em wordpress? Precisa de algum plugin específico?
Não tenho muito conhecimento por isso pesso ajuda!
Obrigado desde Já!

Answer (score 1):

Recomendo usar o [PushCrew](https://pushcrew.com/) para isso, é bem fácil de configurar e implementar. Faça seu cadastro e personalize a aparência e as mensagens como achar melhor, apesar de ser em inglês é bem fácil de entender.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Você pode fazer o [download do plugin aqui](https://wordpress.org/plugins/pushcrew/) e instalar no seu wordpress. Depois basta acessar as configurações do plugin e inserir sua ID.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]